# canDeactivate() is not triggered on page navigation in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards, candeactivate

I have a requirement of throwing a popup to the user when navigating to different component from the current component.

And based on the input from the user i will have to either have to allow him to navigate away or make him stay.

After a lot of googling i have found out that using a route guard which implements canDeactivate interface is the best approach to this problem.

However even after following a step-by-step process of implementing the guard, the canDeactivate() method implemented in the guard is never triggered on any of the navigations away from my component.

Here is my guard which i have implemented as a service.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SearchProjectComponent } from 'src/app/Project/search-project/search-project.component';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanDeactivateGuard  implements CanDeactivate<SearchProjectComponent> {

    canDeactivate(component: SearchProjectComponent,
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot) {debugger
    alert('called from guard');
    const url: string = state.url;
    console.log('Url: ' + url);

  return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
}
}
```

SearchComponent is my component for which i am trying to implement the Guard. (On navigating away from this component, i want to throw a popup prompt)

Here is my AppRoutingModule

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';
import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './shared/services/can-deactivate-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./layout/layout.module').then(m => m.LayoutModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
    { path: 'access-denied', loadChildren: () => import('./access-denied/access-denied.module').then(m => m.AccessDeniedModule) },
    { path: 'add-project', loadChildren: () => import('./Project/add-project/add-project.module').then(m => m.AddProjectModule) },
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    { path: 'search-project', loadChildren: () => import('./Project/search-project/search-project.module').then(m => m.SearchProjectModule), canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'access-denied' },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

On navigating to any other component from searchcomponent, the canDeactivate method doesn't even get triggered.

Here is the code in my component.

```js
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {debugger
    alert('called form component');
    if (this.registerForm.dirty) {debugger
      return false;
        //return this.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes for Person?');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Even the debugger in my component doesn't get triggered.

Can someone help me with what i need to correct?
(I am just a beginner in Angular, but i feel if this issue has something to do with the loadchildren() in the routingmodule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing to implement the `component.canDeactivate` inside your component, which is the only one who knows if the user can leave out or not.

So, inside your components, implements this:

```
canDeactivate(): boolean {
 return //condition to verify;
}
```

For more info, look here:

https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes

Comment: Sorry, i havnt included the code that i have written in my component. As i thought that is called only after the event is fired. Even though there is canDeactivate method in my component the event doesn't fire. I have added the method in my question above.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you r trying to deactivate a set of lazy loaded routes. Try to apply the CanDeactivateGuard to the internal routes of the feature module you are loading instead.